# Cancel button should exit the sub

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dialog box to pick a folder name and display the name of the folder that the user selects.

If the user selects cancel instead of folder path and OK, it throws an error.

I used a status variable and noticed that upon cancel the status changes to -1. So I tried to implement the code that is in comment section using a if condition to exit the sub.

That doesn't work in the case of selecting a folder when the commented part is present in the code.

Without that it works in selecting a folder.

```
sub abc()
    Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
        diaFolder.Title = "Select a folder then hit OK"
        diaFolder.Show
        'Status = diaFolder.Show
        'If Status < 0 Then
        'Exit Sub
        'End If
        a = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)

        MsgBox ("Folder selected is :" & a)
ens sub
```

Comment: If (diaFolder.SelectedItems.Count <= 0) Then
            MsgBox ("No folders selected.")
            Exit Sub
        End If

Comment: dee, please create an answer so the user can accept it and everybody knows the problem is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Keep in mind that vbFalse = 0 and vbTrue = -1.
In other words clicking 'OK' would return -1 and clicking 'Cancel' would return 0.

Try the following code:

```
Sub abc()
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select a folder then hit OK"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            MsgBox ("Folder selected is :" & .SelectedItems(1))
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub abc()
 Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diaFolder.Title = "Select a folder then hit OK"
    Dim status As Integer
    status = diaFolder.Show
    If status <> -1 Then
    MsgBox "Cancel Chosen"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    a = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)
    MsgBox ("Folder selected is :" & a)
End Sub
```

I know this is closed out but wanted to try posting for the first time. =D

Answer (score 1):

If there are no items selected, *SelectedItems(1)*doesn't exist, and Excel will return an error. That's what's happening when the user presses the *Cancel* button.

A solution for this is to check how many items are selected using the structure  below:

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    'Optional: limits the user to choosing a single option. Necessary if you want to avoid an error because the user selected multiple files.
    .Title = "Dialog Title" 'Changing the title is also Optional
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Canceled by user" 'or just do nothing!
    Else
        MyVar = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    'Alternatively, "if .selecteditems.count = 1 then myvar = .selecteditems(1)" can be used
End With
```